# Compile flags number 16

Tags: python, regex

What does the number 16 mean? Are there other options of numbers?

```
re.compile('(<.*?>)', flags=16)
```

As far as I know, flags should like re.I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a "constant".

```
>>> re.S
16
```

Of course you should always be writing `flags=re.S` instead of `flags=16`, but the result is the same.

Comment: when i read other one's code, it's painful to see these numbers.

Comment: @metaphy: And you should share your pain with them. Via a baseball bat.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you know if these constants will be replaced by Enums in python3.4?

Comment: The doc should note these numbers

Comment: @metaphy: I disagree. You should never be using magic numbers, and if you need to find out because some fool decided to do so anyway, you can always open the interpreter and check them yourself. That's what I did when I read your question. Although I didn't have to search long because `re.S` was the only modifier that made any sense with your regex.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: This may be the answer to my second question.

Answer (score 4):

The flags passed to re.compile are what's called a 'bitfield' or 'bitset' or 'bitwise flags'.

Every single flag that you can pass has a different value - 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc...

These values are special - they're perfect powers of 2. When you view a number in binary, they set exactly one bit and do nothing to other bits - 2 is 0b10, 4 is 0b100, 8 is 0b1000, 16 is 0b10000 and so on. That means that you can specify the presence and absence of each flag in a single integer number by making each flag == one separate bit. For example, 12 is two flags - 4 and 8, because it is 0b1100.